# How to do a Shapiro wilks test on 73 variables in R

Tags: r, loops, variables

I have a data set with **6** different **groups**, who each have **73** variables. So I want to test each variable for normality within each group.

I have figured out how to do the `shaprio.test(data$IL8)`, however can I not figure out how to set it in a loop so I don't have to do it 438 times.

Which parameters should I consider and how do I go about it?

I hope you can help in a language I can understand.

Best whishes, 
A lost PhD studen,
Olivia Lie-Andersen

Comment: I don't quite understand the structure of your data, could you post a subset of it to help us out? Just a few of the groups and a few of the variables, needn't be realistic, just representative. `dput()` could be useful for this.

Comment: Hello Olivia, I think the apply() function can help you with this problem.

Comment: If you can post a minimal example, you'd get better help. As it stands, it sounds like a straightforward task with `dplyr::group_by()` and then applying your function on each group.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data and expected output. You can find more details on what constitutes a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).